# Is it possible to avoid namespace boilerplate in a header file?

Tags: c++, namespaces, boilerplate

I have some helper classes that I don't want in the global namespace, so I want to put them in their own namespace.  For example:

```
// Widget.h
namespace MyHelpers {
    class Helper { ... };
}

class Foo {
    void bar(MyHelpers::Helper *helper);
}

// Widget.cpp
using namespace MyHelpers;

Foo::bar(Helper *helper) { ... }
```

In in the .cpp file, Helper can be referenced directly, while in the .h file, it is referenced using the namespace.  Is it possible to have the header file lose the "MyHelpers::" boilerplate, while still reserving MyHelpers from the global namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have many of these, create a type shortcut inside the using class declaration:

```
class Foo {
    ...
    typedef MyHelpers::Helper Helper;
    ...
    void bar(Helper *helper);
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative could be to nest the helper classes inside the main class.
Something like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    class Helper { ... };
    void bar(Helper *helper);
}
```

Then:

```
Foo foo;
Foo::Helper helper;
foo.bar(&helper);
```